# TypeError: omer.sort is not a function

Tags: axios, next.js, strapi

i'm working on a nextjs and strapi project but i can't get the data from strapi. When i try to get data i'm getting "TypeError: omer.sort is not a function" error and i can;t resolve it. I need help ;/

here is code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


function ABC() {
  const [omer, setOmer] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    async function fetchData(){
      setLoading(true)
      try {
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/omers')
        console.log(result)
        setOmer(result.data)
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error){
        setError(error)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
{
  omer.sort((a,b) => b.created_at.localeCompare(a.created_at)).map(omer=>{
    return(
      <div
      style={{
        width: "60%",
        margin: "auto",
        padding:"20px",
        marginBottom: "15px",
        border:"1px solid coral",
        borderRadius:"10px"
      }}
      key={omer.id}>
        <h3>{omer.title}</h3>
        

      </div>
    )
  })
}
}


export default ABC;
```

Comment: If you log `result.data` to the console, what do you get? Also, unless you've omitted some code in the JSX section, that code is not valid and won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statement.

```
function ABC() {
  const [omer, setOmer] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/omers");
        console.log(result);
        setOmer(result.data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <p>Is loading...</p>}
      {omer
        .sort((a, b) => b.created_at.localeCompare(a.created_at))
        .map((omer) => {
          return (
            <div
              style={{
                width: "60%",
                margin: "auto",
                padding: "20px",
                marginBottom: "15px",
                border: "1px solid coral",
                borderRadius: "10px",
              }}
              key={omer.id}
            >
              <h3>{omer.title}</h3>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```